# Клонировать android репозитории

Tags: java, android, git, github

Нашёл вроде как интересный [проект](https://github.com/jiujiteiro/SoccerGameAndroid) на гитхабе, да и просто на будущее решил пробовать клонировать и смотреть как проекты запускаются. Склонировал, вроде всё как надо, но увы ни build.gradle ни кнопки запуска(я про Shift f10) не отображается, тупо серая. Вот и собственно вопрос, как запускать склонированные проекты? Ради интереса, можете объяснить на предоставленном выше.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проект создан без системы сборки (Gradle/Maven), поэтому импортировать его нужно как обычный Android-проект (Android-Studio/Idea).

Или можно использовать стандартную утилиту `adb` для установки на эмулятор:

```
adb install [.apk путь]
```

Comment: в смысле как обычный Android проект? 
я делаю через git clone и адрес который есть в гитхабе. Или как правильноей? можно поподробней. 
а со вторым способом .apk путь в моём репозитории где будет находится апк типо?

Comment: Импортировать через IDE. Без IDE будет довольно тяжело собрать проект. Для этого вам вручную нужно будет создать R.java, скомпилировать все java файлы через `javac`, перевести все class-файлы в dex через `dx` и сгенерировать из них apk через `aapt`.

Comment: И только после этого можно будет сгенеренный файл загрузить на устройство через `adb install`.

Answer (score 1):

Проще говоря можете сначала склонировать репозиторий, куда Вам будет угодно с помощью команды `git clone`, после чего делаем Import Project и докачиваете нужные SDK если то потребуется, после чего сможете запустить скачанный проект.

Второй способ - добавить run configuration и прописать в нём настройки запуска по default'у. (что то типо Deploy: Default APK, Launch: Default Activity, Module:app)